# Removing uses of TestFlight SDK with ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard, testflight

How can I automatically remove all uses of TestFlight SDK from my app? For example, all `passCheckpoint` calls:

```
TestFlight.passCheckpoint("FreemiumDialog opened");
```

My (ProGuard-obfuscated) release builds should not even attempt to send any info to TestFlight, yet I do not want to manually toggle between having TestFlight jar & its uses in my codebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ProGuard configuration removes all calls to TestFlight SDK:

```
# Remove all TestFlight SDK calls, e.g. TestFlight.takeOff( ... );
# and TestFlight.passCheckpoint( ... );
-assumenosideeffects class com.testflightapp.lib.TestFlight { *; }

-dontwarn org.msgpack.**
```

Note: without the last line, ProGuard fails with a bunch of warnings like:

> Warning: org.msgpack.template.builder.BeansBuildContext: can't find
>   referenced class javassist.CtClass
>   Warning: org.msgpack.util.json.JSONUnpacker: can't find referenced class > org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser

This is because the TestFlightLib jar (at least version 1.3) contains and uses a library called [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org). We need to either -keep it or mute the warnings. Above I'm muting warnings, since the whole point here is *not* to use TestFlight in release builds.